# Creating lists from text file

Tags: python, external

I want to create lists, but have the **name of the lists** in an external file called "mydog.txt".

**mydog.txt**:

```
bingo
bango
smelly
wongo
```

Here is my code that converts the text into list elements. I think it works but for some reason, the values are not saved after it's finished:

```
def createlist(nameoflist):
    nameoflist = ["test"]
    print(nameoflist)

file = open("mydog.txt")
for i in file.readlines():
    i= i.replace("\n", "")
    print(i) #making sure text is ready to be created into a list name
    createlist(i)
file.close()
print("FOR fuction complete")

print(bingo) # I try to print this but it does not exist, yet it has been printed in the function
```

The subroutine is supposed to take a name (let's say "bingo") and then turn it into a list and have `"test"` inside of that list.

The final variables i should have are "bingo = ["test"], bango = ["test"], smelly = ["test"], wongo = ["test"]

The final thing that should be printed is `['test']` but the list does not exist.

Why does it print out as a list when inside of the subroutine `createlist` but not outside the subroutine?

Comment: I am confused if you want to initialize `nameoflist` inside the function so what exactly you are passing in `createlist` function?

Comment: "i" takes place in "nameoflist" and "i" takes place in one of the values in my text file.

Comment: Create in a text file, or create from a text file?

Comment: This code does not appear to make much sense at all...

Comment: @MadPhysicist create list from a text file.

Comment: @kurpingspaceproductions. Can you please edit your question to include the information on what you are trying to do? That was very difficult to figure out from reading the question.

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: See if using `exec` works for you as I said in my answer below. You need not return, I misunderstood initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `exec`:

```
with open('mydog.txt') as f:
    list_names = [line.strip() for line in f]

for name in list_names:
    exec('{} = ["test"]'.format(name))

local = locals()
for name in list_names:
    print ('list_name:', name, ', value:', local[name])
```

or

```
print (bingo, bango, smelly, wongo)
```

output:

```
list_name: bingo , value: ['test']
list_name: bango , value: ['test']
list_name: smelly , value: ['test']
list_name: wongo , value: ['test']

or 

['test'] ['test'] ['test'] ['test']
```

Comment: this is perfect! thank you so much!
by the way, you are missing brackets () for `print`

Comment: thanks. tested on python 2.7 which doesn't need (). I guess you are using python 3.x

Comment: yeah i am using 3.x

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("mydog.txt")
my_list =file.read().splitlines() # will create the list from the file which should contain only names without '\n'
file.close()
```

Or `with` block to not worry about file closing

```
with open("mydog.txt") as file:
    my_list =file.read().splitlines() # will create the list from the file which should contain only names without '\n'
```

In case you want to create the lists named after the names present in the text files you really should be creating a `dict` with keys as the names and value as list containing string `test`

```
my_dict={i:['test'] for i in my_list}
```

Then try to print

```
print(my_dict['bingo']) # will print list ['test']
```

Printing entire dict

```
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'bango': ['test'], 'bingo': ['test'], 'smelly': ['test'], 'wongo': ['test']}
```

Comment: You really should use a with block

Comment: how do i add "my_dict={i:['test'] for i in my_list}" into my code so i can test to see if it works? by the way "splitlines" does not exist for some reason and i don't know why. it returns attribute error

Comment: Just start coping over the code should work if everything you posted is similar to your actual environment. Edited my answer for that error. missed `()` after read

Comment: thank you alot, this works perfectly. also thank you for introducing me into dictionaries

Comment: @kurpingspaceproductions your welcome you should look for data structure that matches your requirement. creating a variable is okay if there are 2,3 values but same  might not be feasible if there are millions of names. Good luck

Comment: `mydog.txt` is just a sample, i have a text file with alot more names on, this is why i am using a .txt file. i am also planning on replacing "test" with a random number, along with 2 other random numbers. this all works out for me so this code is perfect

Answer (score 0):

1. You are adding variables to the local namespace of the function. Nothing you add like that will be visible outside the function.
2. The assignment you are making is to a variable named by `nameoflist`, not the string that it refers to.

To get around that, you have to assign to the module namespace. This is actually not that difficult:

```
def createlist(nameoflist):
    globals()[nameoflist] = ["test"]
```

The question you have to ask yourself is why you want to do that. Let's say you load your file:

```
with open("mydog.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        createlist(line.strip())
```

Now indeed you can do

```
>>> print(bingo)
['test']
```

However, the whole point of using a file is to have dynamic names. You don't know what names you will get up front, and once you stick them into the global namespace, you won't know which variables came from the file and which ones from elsewhere.

Keep in mind that the global namespace is just a fancy but regular dictionary. My recommendation is to hold the variables in your own dictionary, just for the purpose instead:

```
with open("mydog.txt") as f:
    mylists = {line.strip(): ['test'] for line in f}
```

Now you can access the items by name:

```
>>> mylists['bingo']
['test']
```

But more importantly, you can check what names you got and actually manipulate them in a meaningful way:

```
>>> list(mylists.keys())
['bingo', 'bango', 'smelly', 'wongo']
```

Comment: this is somewhat helpful, for me this is very hard to understand but i think i got it after staring at it long enough.

so i figured out you could type in shell and it actually returns some values. (i tried doing mylists["bingo"] in the actual code instead of python lol)

Comment: i am still confused as to how to actually use these new objects, as i cannot manipulate these lists at all, for example using normal list commands like "append" or "pop"

Comment: @kurpingspaceproductions. I have trouble believing that.

Comment: ok, just to make sure.
1. "bingo", "bango", "smelly" and "wongo" are all lists or dictionaries or other?
2. "mylists" is a list that contains my lists right?

Comment: The names are all set to lists containing a single element `test`. `mylists` is a dictionary containing your lists. Please just run the code and play with it.